# Adguard adds adware like JavaScript code to each page render. What is it?

Tags: malware, web-browser

I'm using Firefox 101.0.1 with the extension [AdGuard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adguard-adblocker/) from the official Firefox add-ons page. When this extension is activated, I find strange adware like JavaScript code with the dev tools, evaluated for each page render.

[image: Evidence: Logs in the console]

When I search for the origin of this logs I find the following:

[image: Evidence: Sandbox eval code]

```
            (function () {
                try {
                    var AG_onLoad=function(func){if(document.readyState==="complete"||document.readyState==="interactive")func();else if(document.addEventListener)document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",func);else if(document.attachEvent)document.attachEvent("DOMContentLoaded",func)};
var AG_removeElementById = function(id) { var element = document.getElementById(id); if (element && element.parentNode) { element.parentNode.removeChild(element); }};
var AG_removeElementBySelector = function(selector) { if (!document.querySelectorAll) { return; } var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector); if (nodes) { for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) { if (nodes[i] && nodes[i].parentNode) { nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]); } } } };
var AG_each = function(selector, fn) { if (!document.querySelectorAll) return; var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector); for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { fn(elements[i]); }; };
var AG_removeParent = function(el, fn) { while (el && el.parentNode) { if (fn(el)) { el.parentNode.removeChild(el); return; } el = el.parentNode; } };
var AG_removeCookie=function(a){var e=/./;/^\/.+\/$/.test(a)?e=new RegExp(a.slice(1,-1)):""!==a&&(e=new RegExp(a.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g,"\\$&")));a=function(){for(var a=document.cookie.split(";"),g=a.length;g--;){cookieStr=a[g];var d=cookieStr.indexOf("=");if(-1!==d&&(d=cookieStr.slice(0,d).trim(),e.test(d)))for(var h=document.location.hostname.split("."),f=0;f<h.length-1;f++){var b=h.slice(f).join(".");if(b){var c=d+"=",k="; domain="+b;b="; domain=."+b;document.cookie=c+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";document.cookie=c+k+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";document.cookie=c+b+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";document.cookie=c+"; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";document.cookie=c+k+"; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";document.cookie=c+b+"; path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"}}}};a();window.addEventListener("beforeunload",a)};
var AG_defineProperty=function(){var p,q=Object.defineProperty;if("function"==typeof WeakMap)p=WeakMap;else{var r=0,t=function(){this.a=(r+=Math.random()).toString()};t.prototype.set=function(a,b){var d=a[this.a];d&&d[0]===a?d[1]=b:q(a,this.a,{value:[a,b],writable:!0});return this};t.prototype.get=function(a){var b;return(b=a[this.a])&&b[0]===a?b[1]:void 0};t.prototype.has=function(a){var b=a[this.a];return b?b[0]===a:!1};p=t}function u(a){this.b=a;this.h=Object.create(null)}function v(a,b,d,e){this.a=a;this.i=b;this.c=d;this.f=e}function w(){this.g=/^([^\\\.]|\\.)*?\./;this.j=/\\(.)/g;this.a=new p}function x(a,b){var d=b.f;if(d&&!("beforeGet"in d||"beforeSet"in d))return z(d);var e={get:function(){var c=b.f;c&&c.beforeGet&&c.beforeGet.call(this,b.a.b);a:if(c=b.g)c=A(c)?c.value:c.get?c.get.call(this):void 0;else{c=b.a.b;if(b.i in c&&(c=B(c),null!==c)){var d=C.call(c,b.i);c=d?d.call(this):c[b.i];break a}c=void 0}(this===b.a.b||D.call(b.a.b,this))&&E(a,c,b.c);return c},set:function(c){if(this===b.a.b||D.call(b.a.b,this)){b.f&&b.f.beforeSet&&(c=b.f.beforeSet.call(this,c,this));var d=b.g;d&&A(d)&&d.value===c?c=!0:(d=F(b,c,this),G(c)&&(c=H(a,c),I(a,c,b.c)),c=d)}else c=F(b,c,this);return c}};d&&J(d,e,K);return e}function I(a,b,d){for(var e in d.h){var c=d.h[e];if(b.h[e]){var h=a,g=b.h[e],k=c;!k.f||g.f||"undefined"===typeof g.a.b||g.g||(g.g=z(k.f));g.c&&k.c&&g.c!==k.c&&I(h,g.c,k.c)}else{g=h=void 0;k=a;var f=b,l=c.i,m="undefined"!==typeof f.b,y=!1;m&&(g=L(f.b,l))&&!g.configurable&&(y=!0,h=f.b[l]);var n=y?H(k,h):new u(c.c.b);I(k,n,c.c);n=new v(f,l,n,c.f);f.h[l]=n;m&&(n.g=g,m=x(k,n),y?E(k,h,c.c):(q(f.b,l,m),g&&A(g)&&(M(m,g.value,f.b),E(k,g.value,c.c))))}}}function E(a,b,d){G(b)&&(b=H(a,b),I(a,b,d))}function F(a,b,d){var e=a.g;if(!e){e=B(a.a.b);if(null!==e&&(e=N.call(e,a.i)))return e.call(d,b);if(!O(a.a.b))return!1;a.g={value:b,configurable:!0,writable:!0,enumerable:!0};return!0}return M(e,b,d)}function H(a,b){var d=a.a.get(b);d||(d=new u(b),a.a.set(b,d));return d}function A(a){return"undefined"!==typeof a.writable}function J(a,b,d){for(var e=0,c=d.length;e<c;e++){var h=d[e];h in a&&(b[h]=a[h])}}function z(a){if(a){var b={};J(a,b,P);return b}}function M(a,b,d){if(A(a))return a.writable?(a.value=b,!0):!1;if(!a.set)return!1;a.set.call(d,b);return!0}var P="configurable enumerable value get set writable".split(" "),K=P.slice(0,2),L=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor,O=Object.isExtensible,B=Object.getPrototypeOf,D=Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf,C=Object.prototype.__lookupGetter__||function(a){return(a=Q(this,a))&&a.get?a.get:void 0},N=Object.prototype.__lookupSetter__||function(a){return(a=Q(this,a))&&a.set?a.set:void 0};function Q(a,b){if(b in a){for(;!w.hasOwnProperty.call(a,b);)a=B(a);return L(a,b)}}function G(a){var b=typeof a;return"function"===b||"object"===b&&null!==a?!0:!1}var R;return function(a,b,d){R||(R=new w);var e=R;d=d||window;var c=new u;a+=".";var h=c||new u;for(var g=e.g,k=e.j,f,l,m;a;){f=g.exec(a);if(null===f)throw 1;f=f[0].length;l=a.slice(0,f-1).replace(k,"$1");a=a.slice(f);(f=h.h[l])?m=f.c:(m=new u,f=new v(h,l,m),h.h[l]=f);h=m}if(!f)throw 1;a=f;a.f=b;E(e,d,c)};}();
var AG_abortOnPropertyWrite=function(a,b){var c=Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,8);AG_defineProperty(a,{beforeSet:function(){b&&console.warn("AdGuard aborted property write: "+a);throw new ReferenceError(c);}});var d=window.onerror;window.onerror=function(e){if("string"===typeof e&&-1!==e.indexOf(c))return b&&console.warn("AdGuard has caught window.onerror: "+a),!0;if(d instanceof Function)return d.apply(this,arguments)}};
var AG_abortOnPropertyRead=function(a,b){var c=Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,8);AG_defineProperty(a,{beforeGet:function(){b&&console.warn("AdGuard aborted property read: "+a);throw new ReferenceError(c);}});var d=window.onerror;window.onerror=function(e){if("string"===typeof e&&-1!==e.indexOf(c))return b&&console.warn("AdGuard has caught window.onerror: "+a),!0;if(d instanceof Function)return d.apply(this,arguments)}};
var AG_abortInlineScript=function(g,b,c){var d=function(){if("currentScript"in document)return document.currentScript;var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script");return a[a.length-1]},e=Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,8),h=d();AG_defineProperty(b,{beforeGet:function(){var a=d();if(a instanceof HTMLScriptElement&&a!==h&&""===a.src&&g.test(a.textContent))throw c&&console.warn("AdGuard aborted execution of an inline script"),new ReferenceError(e);}});var f=window.onerror;window.onerror=function(a){if("string"===typeof a&&-1!==a.indexOf(e))return c&&console.warn("AdGuard has caught window.onerror: "+b),!0;if(f instanceof Function)return f.apply(this,arguments)}};
var AG_setConstant=function(e,a){if("undefined"===a)a=void 0;else if("false"===a)a=!1;else if("true"===a)a=!0;else if("noopFunc"===a)a=function(){};else if("trueFunc"===a)a=function(){return!0};else if("falseFunc"===a)a=function(){return!1};else if(/^\d+$/.test(a)){if(a=parseFloat(a),isNaN(a)||32767<Math.abs(a))return}else return;var b=!1;AG_defineProperty(e,{get:function(){return a},set:function(c){if(b)var d=!0;else void 0!==c&&void 0!==a&&typeof c!==typeof a&&(b=!0),d=b;d&&(a=c)}})};
(function(source, args){
function setConstant(source, property, value, stack) {
          if (!property || !matchStackTrace(stack, new Error().stack)) {
            return;
          }
          var log = console.log.bind(console);
          var emptyArr = noopArray();
          var emptyObj = noopObject();
          var constantValue;
          if (value === 'undefined') {
            constantValue = undefined;
          } else if (value === 'false') {
            constantValue = false;
          } else if (value === 'true') {
            constantValue = true;
          } else if (value === 'null') {
            constantValue = null;
          } else if (value === 'emptyArr') {
            constantValue = emptyArr;
          } else if (value === 'emptyObj') {
            constantValue = emptyObj;
          } else if (value === 'noopFunc') {
            constantValue = noopFunc;
          } else if (value === 'trueFunc') {
            constantValue = trueFunc;
          } else if (value === 'falseFunc') {
            constantValue = falseFunc;
          } else if (value === 'noopPromiseResolve') {
            constantValue = noopPromiseResolve;
          } else if (value === 'noopPromiseReject') {
            constantValue = noopPromiseReject;
          } else if (/^\d+$/.test(value)) {
            constantValue = parseFloat(value);
            if (nativeIsNaN(constantValue)) {
              return;
            }
            if (Math.abs(constantValue) > 0x7FFF) {
              return;
            }
          } else if (value === '-1') {
            constantValue = -1;
          } else if (value === '') {
            constantValue = '';
          } else if (value === 'yes') {
            constantValue = 'yes';
          } else if (value === 'no') {
            constantValue = 'no';
          } else {
            return;
          }
          var getCurrentScript = function getCurrentScript() {
            if ('currentScript' in document) {
              return document.currentScript;
            }
            var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
            return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
          };
          var ourScript = getCurrentScript();
          var canceled = false;
          var mustCancel = function mustCancel(value) {
            if (canceled) {
              return canceled;
            }
            canceled = value !== undefined && constantValue !== undefined && typeof value !== typeof constantValue;
            return canceled;
          };
          var trapProp = function trapProp(base, prop, configurable, handler) {
            if (!handler.init(base[prop])) {
              return false;
            }
            var origDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(base, prop);
            var prevGetter;
            var prevSetter;
            if (origDescriptor instanceof Object) {
              if (!origDescriptor.configurable) {
                if (source.verbose) {
                  log("set-constant: property '".concat(prop, "' is not configurable"));
                }
                return false;
              }
              base[prop] = constantValue;
              if (origDescriptor.get instanceof Function) {
                prevGetter = origDescriptor.get;
              }
              if (origDescriptor.set instanceof Function) {
                prevSetter = origDescriptor.set;
              }
            }
            Object.defineProperty(base, prop, {
              configurable: configurable,
              get: function get() {
                if (prevGetter !== undefined) {
                  prevGetter();
                }
                return handler.get();
              },
              set: function set(a) {
                if (prevSetter !== undefined) {
                  prevSetter(a);
                }
                handler.set(a);
              }
            });
            return true;
          };
          var setChainPropAccess = function setChainPropAccess(owner, property) {
            var chainInfo = getPropertyInChain(owner, property);
            var base = chainInfo.base;
            var prop = chainInfo.prop,
                chain = chainInfo.chain;
            var undefPropHandler = {
              factValue: undefined,
              init: function init(a) {
                this.factValue = a;
                return true;
              },
              get: function get() {
                return this.factValue;
              },
              set: function set(a) {
                if (this.factValue === a) {
                  return;
                }
                this.factValue = a;
                if (a instanceof Object) {
                  setChainPropAccess(a, chain);
                }
              }
            };
            var endPropHandler = {
              factValue: undefined,
              init: function init(a) {
                if (mustCancel(a)) {
                  return false;
                }
                this.factValue = a;
                return true;
              },
              get: function get() {
                return document.currentScript === ourScript ? this.factValue : constantValue;
              },
              set: function set(a) {
                if (!mustCancel(a)) {
                  return;
                }
                constantValue = a;
              }
            };
            if (!chain) {
              var isTrapped = trapProp(base, prop, false, endPropHandler);
              if (isTrapped) {
                hit(source);
              }
              return;
            }
            var propValue = owner[prop];
            if (propValue instanceof Object || typeof propValue === 'object' && propValue !== null) {
              setChainPropAccess(propValue, chain);
            }
            trapProp(owner, prop, true, undefPropHandler);
          };
          setChainPropAccess(window, property);
        }
function hit(source, message) {
          if (source.verbose !== true) {
            return;
          }
          try {
            var log = console.log.bind(console);
            var trace = console.trace.bind(console);
            var prefix = source.ruleText || '';
            if (source.domainName) {
              var AG_SCRIPTLET_MARKER = '#%#//';
              var UBO_SCRIPTLET_MARKER = '##+js';
              var ruleStartIndex;
              if (source.ruleText.indexOf(AG_SCRIPTLET_MARKER) > -1) {
                ruleStartIndex = source.ruleText.indexOf(AG_SCRIPTLET_MARKER);
              } else if (source.ruleText.indexOf(UBO_SCRIPTLET_MARKER) > -1) {
                ruleStartIndex = source.ruleText.indexOf(UBO_SCRIPTLET_MARKER);
              }
              var rulePart = source.ruleText.slice(ruleStartIndex);
              prefix = "".concat(source.domainName).concat(rulePart);
            }
            var LOG_MARKER = 'log: ';
            if (message) {
              if (message.indexOf(LOG_MARKER) === -1) {
                log("".concat(prefix, " message:\n").concat(message));
              } else {
                log(message.slice(LOG_MARKER.length));
              }
            }
            log("".concat(prefix, " trace start"));
            if (trace) {
              trace();
            }
            log("".concat(prefix, " trace end"));
          } catch (e) {
          }
          if (typeof window.__debug === 'function') {
            window.__debug(source);
          }
        }
function noopArray() {
          return [];
        }
function noopObject() {
          return {};
        }
function noopFunc() {}
function trueFunc() {
          return true;
        }
function falseFunc() {
          return false;
        }
function noopPromiseReject() {
          return Promise.reject();
        }
function noopPromiseResolve() {
          return Promise.resolve(new Response());
        }
function getPropertyInChain(base, chain) {
          var pos = chain.indexOf('.');
          if (pos === -1) {
            return {
              base: base,
              prop: chain
            };
          }
          var prop = chain.slice(0, pos);
          if (base === null) {
            return {
              base: base,
              prop: prop,
              chain: chain
            };
          }
          var nextBase = base[prop];
          chain = chain.slice(pos + 1);
          if (nextBase !== undefined) {
            return getPropertyInChain(nextBase, chain);
          }
          Object.defineProperty(base, prop, {
            configurable: true
          });
          return {
            base: nextBase,
            prop: prop,
            chain: chain
          };
        }
function setPropertyAccess(object, property, descriptor) {
          var currentDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property);
          if (currentDescriptor && !currentDescriptor.configurable) {
            return false;
          }
          Object.defineProperty(object, property, descriptor);
          return true;
        }
function toRegExp() {
          var input = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : '';
          var DEFAULT_VALUE = '.?';
          var FORWARD_SLASH = '/';
          if (input === '') {
            return new RegExp(DEFAULT_VALUE);
          }
          if (input[0] === FORWARD_SLASH && input[input.length - 1] === FORWARD_SLASH) {
            return new RegExp(input.slice(1, -1));
          }
          var escaped = input.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
          return new RegExp(escaped);
        }
function matchStackTrace(stackMatch, stackTrace) {
          if (!stackMatch || stackMatch === '') {
            return true;
          }
          var stackRegexp = toRegExp(stackMatch);
          var refinedStackTrace = stackTrace.split('\n').slice(2)
          .map(function (line) {
            return line.trim();
          })
          .join('\n');
          return stackRegexp.test(refinedStackTrace);
        }
function nativeIsNaN(num) {
          var native = Number.isNaN || window.isNaN;
          return native(num);
        };
        const updatedArgs = args ? [].concat(source).concat(args) : [source];
        try {
            setConstant.apply(this, updatedArgs);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    
})({"args":["PartnersCoupang","undefined"],"engine":"extension","name":"set-constant","ruleText":"~coupang.com,~coupangcdn.com#%#//scriptlet(\"set-constant\", \"PartnersCoupang\", \"undefined\")","verbose":true,"version":"4.0.181"}, ["PartnersCoupang","undefined"]);
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.error('Error executing AG js: ' + ex);
                }
            })();
```

I've troubles to find the origin for this inside the AdGuard extension and is quite fishy to me, as "coupang" is a South Korean e commerce company and I have no ties with them. I also started to search inside the blocking list subscriptions I have, but no clue so far. How can I investigate this further?

[image]

Comment: Might have something to do with [this](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardFilters/issues/42304), but I have not looked into the source (if it even exists) to see which commit added that line.

Comment: Isn't the trace just logging what it does when it uses a filter? What makes you think this looks like adware?

Comment: Well its a huge Javascript which is loaded additionally, with references to a South Korean e-commerce platform. It's suspicious to me.

Comment: does it go away when disabling ad guard? if so, well, there you go.

Comment: Yes it goes away if I disable adguard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick skim-through of the code suggests to me that this script is part of AdGuard, used to implement their scriptlet filter list rules.

The AdGuard documentation has [this to say about scriptlets](https://kb.adguard.com/en/general/how-to-create-your-own-ad-filters#scriptlet-rules):

> Scriptlet is a JavaScript function that provides extended capabilities for content blocking. These functions can be used in a declarative manner in AdGuard filtering rules.
>
> **Syntax:**
>
> rule = [domains]  "#%#//scriptlet(" scriptletName arguments ")"

The end of the script you posted references the following rule, which seems to match the syntax in the AdGuard documentation:

`~coupang.com,~coupangcdn.com#%#//scriptlet("set-constant", "PartnersCoupang", "undefined")`

In this case the rule appears to be using the [`set-constant`](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/Scriptlets/blob/master/wiki/about-scriptlets.md#-%EF%B8%8F-set-constant) scriptlet to undefine the `PartnersCoupang` constant in the context of the page you're viewing, probably as part of some effort to block functionality of a tracking or ad script on the host page.